# Searching Computer Names from AD in MOSS 2007

Tags: search, sharepoint-2007, system

In MOSS 2007, I want to search/get Computer Names from Active Directory in SharePoint just like search users.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to retrieve these names programmatically:

As far as I know there is no SharePoint API to retrieve computer names from the AD.
Though there are methods on `SPUtility` to retrieve Users and Groups from the AD.
To query computer names you have to implement you own Ldap query:

Use the .Net types `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` / `System.DirectoryServices.DirecorySearcher` to query against the AD.
If you were using .Net 3.5 you could use the types `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ComputerPrincipal` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher` to do so.